How can I programmatically get information about the status of the Bonding Curve token on pump.fun and its price?
How can I programmatically get this data? I see this data on the site and I've also seen some queries on pumpportal.fun, but there's no query on how to retrieve this data. Please help



I might be wrong, but I don't think they are OS

You can use PumpFun SDK for that
https://github.com/rckprtr/pumpdotfun-sdk
Method you should call is here
https://github.com/rckprtr/pumpdotfun-sdk/blob/main/src/bondingCurveAccount.ts#L30
